# How do you view multiple values using iterator?

Tags: c++

Say I have an `unordered_map<int> map`, I normally use an iterator `for` loop to view all the values in the map, but I ran into a problem where I wish to view two values at once, say the current and the next (if not `nullptr`). How would I set up that loop?

Comment: ? so just increment the iterator and it will point to the next value..

Comment: Try record previous one and compare with current one. If not range loop but a for loop, just compare it and (it+1). Don't forget to deal with edge cases.

Comment: Reminder: Before you operate on a value and the next value, make sure there IS a next value.

Comment: Or perhaps better, start with an iteration with the 2nd element and use, e.g. `i-1` and `i` to output two elements -- that way you cannot attempt to access beyond the end of your map.

Comment: Use two iterators. One starts at the first element, the other at the second, and you increment both of them in each iteration.

Answer (score 4):

It is fairly straightforward.

```
   auto itr1 = map.begin();
   for(auto itr2 = itr1++; itr1!=map.end(); itr2=itr1++)
   {
         // do stuff
   }
```

Though, honestly it is rather meaningless to have access to two conclusive elements of an unordered map as there is no dependency between their keys.

Edit: But if you wish to access next map's element index-based (i and i+1) - and not via the semi-random order that `unordered_map` stores its elements - then you'll have to utilise `find` or change `unordered_map` to `map` if you really need it.

Comment: That's about as fair an example and answer as could be done for the question. Well done with the discussion on the *dubious nature* of iterating the *unordered*_map as a container.

Comment: Sorry I appreciate your answer, I am new to maps and such and I didn't realize unordered maps were not separated by keys and misunderstood the use case. Thanks